# Convert Integer to 4 byte ungisned char vector (in Big endian byte order)

Tags: c++

Suppose, I wanted to write decimal 31 in a binary file (which is already loaded into vector) in 4 bytes so I have to write as 00 00 00 1f, but I don't know how to convert decimal number in hex string (of 4 bytes)

So, expected hex in vector of unsigned char is:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1f // int value of this is 31
```

To do this I tried following:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(int) * 2) << std::hex << 31;
cout << stream.str();
```

**Output:**

```
0000001f
```

Above line of code gives output in string format but I want it into vector of unsigned char in format of '0x', so my output vector should have elements after conversion as 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F.

Comment: What is your problem? Formatting it like that or getting the values in the vector?

Comment: @Timo, I am not able to get values in the vector of unsigned char.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It is `4` in all common platforms today, so you get `setw(8)`.

Comment: @Timo, Actually suppose, I wanted to write decimal 31 in a binary file in 4 bytes so I have to write as 00 00 00 1f, but I don't know how to convert decimal number in hex string (of 4 bytes)

Comment: @hyde Which is the correct number of hexadecimal digits. :)

Comment: @hyde And it is exactly what the OP wants. One byte takes 2 hexadecimal digits. So if you want to display an `int` in hexadecimal, you'll need `sizeof(int) * 2` digits.

Comment: _"Actually suppose, I wanted to write decimal 31 in a binary file in 4 bytes"_. If you write an integer in a binary stream that is exactly what happens. No need to convert anything (given correct endianess).

Comment: @Timo, But I don't that file stream, File is loaded in into vector of unsigned char, and now I want to write some decimal number in that buffer and later on that buffer will be written into a new file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without bothering with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) you could copy the `int` value into a character buffer of the appropriate size. This buffer could be the vector itself.

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> int_to_vector(unsigned value)
{
    // Create a vector of unsigned characters (bytes on a byte-oriented platform)
    // The size will be set to the same size as the value type
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(sizeof value);

    // Do a byte-wise copy of the value into the vector data
    std::memcpy(buffer.data(), &value, sizeof value);

    return buffer;
}
```

The order of bytes in the vector will always in the host native order. If a specific order is mandated then each byte of the multi-byte value needs to be copied into a specific element of the array using bitwise operations (`std::memcpy` can't be used).

Also note that this function will break strict aliasing if `uint8_t` isn't an alias of `unsigned char`. And that `uint8_t` is an optional type, there are platforms which doesn't have 8-bit entities (though they are not common).

---

For an endianness-specific variant, where each value of a byte is extracted one by one and added to the vector, perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> int_to_be_vector(unsigned value)
{
    // Create a vector of unsigned characters (bytes on a byte-oriented platform)
    // The size will be set to the same size as the value type
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(sizeof value);

    // For each byte in the multi-byte value, copy it to the "correct" place in the vector
    for (size_t i = buffer.size(); i > 0; --i)
    {
        // The cast truncates the value, dropping all but the lowest eight bits
        buffer[i - 1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(value);
        value >>= 8;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

[Example of it working](https://godbolt.org/z/rz6ePc)

Comment: Couldn't we also memcpy directly into `vector::data` (given the vector is resized accordingly)?

Comment: @Timo I'm not sure, considering strict aliasing and all that. I'm not actually sure that the temporary array could be `uint8_t`, or if it must be `char`.

Comment: That's what I'm stuggling with aswell. But is there a difference to your example in that regard? I mean does using that temporary buffer affect aliasing differently compared to `vector::data`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and @Timo Actually [std::vector::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) is a `T*` so for a`std::vector<unsigned char>` it should be safe (no strict aliasing violation, am I right ?).

Comment: @Fareanor that's what I thought aswell. But Some programmer dude knows the standard better than I do so I'd like his opinion on that matter.

Comment: @Timo Agreed, that's what I'm asking for too :p

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this works as expected, but returned vector has little endian byte order. but the buffer (into which I want to append this returned vector) is in big endian order, so can I deal with this?

Comment: @Amogh As mentioned my function doesn't bother with the endianness issue. A simple way to change endianness is to simply reverse the vector.

Comment: Oh! @Someprogrammerdude so in short u mean to say this function will always gives hex in little endian (irrespective of machine/platform) to make it big endian I jsut have to reverse.

Comment: @Amogh Wrong, he wants to say that this function will always use the system/platform endianness (therefore little endian if your system is little-endian, big-endian otherwise). If you want to change it, you can reverse the vector as mentioned.

Comment: Okay, got that.

Comment: @Amogh Updated with a version to get a big-endianness vector

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop to extract one byte at a time of the original number and store that in a vector.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using u8 = std::uint8_t;
using u32 = std::uint32_t;

std::vector<u8> GetBytes(const u32 number) {
    const u32 mask{0xFF};
    u32 remaining{number};

    std::vector<u8> result{};
    while (remaining != 0u) {
        const u32 bits{remaining & mask};
        const u8 res{static_cast<u8>(bits)};
        result.push_back(res);
        remaining >>= 8u;
    }
    std::reverse(std::begin(result), std::end(result));
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const u32 myNumber{0xABC123};
    const auto bytes{GetBytes(myNumber)};
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
    for (const auto b : bytes) {
        std::cout << static_cast<u32>(b) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
0xab 0xc1 0x23
```